# How to create a loop within this game successfully?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python so I'm not sure how to go about this. I have created this random number guessing game, and I have it down except for the fact that the game is supposed to never end. Once the user guesses the number, the game should start over. Here is my code.

```
import random
num = random.randint(1, 100)

def main():
    guess_num = 0
    guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 100: "))
    while num != guess:
        if guess < num:
            print("Too low, try again.")
            guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 100: "))
            guess_num+=1
        elif guess > num:
            print("Too high, try again.")
            guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 100: "))
            guess_num+=1
        else:
            print("Congratulations, that's correct!")
            guess_num = guess_num+1
            print("You guessed "+str(guess_num)+" times!")
            break
            main()
main()
```

Comment: The call to `main()` inside of the `else` block is never executed because you `break` first.

Comment: just fixed the indents, sorry, it was the copy paste

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    main()
```

This makes your main method run until you stop it.

Comment: The num will always be the same in this case.

Comment: True, fixed easily by defining num inside main() though.

Comment: Note that this is literally an infinite loop with no control other than using `exit()` inside `main`

Answer (score 0):

You put a `break` statement in your `else`. If you remove it it will work. But you also have to put your `num` statement inside your `main`.

This should do the job:

```
def main():
    num = random.randint(1, 100)
    guess_num = 0
    guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 100: "))
    while num != "guess":
        if guess < num:
            print("Too low, try again.")
            guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 100: "))
            guess_num+=1
        elif guess > num:
            print("Too high, try again.")
            guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 100: "))
            guess_num+=1
        else:
            print("Congratulations, that's correct!")
            guess_num = guess_num+1
            print("You guessed "+str(guess_num)+" times!")
            main()

main()
```

Comment: That means you're going to call a while loop inside a while loop when the user wins the game, then a while inside a while inside a while, this slows down performance.

Comment: Yes it's not the way I would have done it. My goal was just to point where the user had problems in his code so he can understand what he did wrong. I just kept it simple for this case.

Comment: I have fixed my code so it loops but the random number does not change, do I need to import random again?

Answer (score 0):

1. All lines down from `def main():` must be indented four spaces. Maybe it's just a problem with the copy paste, but I find myself really uncomfortable looking at improperly indented Python code.
2. Remove the `print` statement right after `while num != "guess":` not sure what it does
3. Remove the quotes around `guess` as right now you're checking a number against a string

Now, to implement your functionality, you should move the `num = random.randint(1, 100)` line into the function to choose a new number. Then, call the function while true:

```py
while True:
    main()
```

Comment: How do I call the function if true? What am I setting to true? I fixed up my code a bit but now it won't print the congratulation message or the guess message.